# Terminal.Gui c# - Is any way to convert Dim to int?

Tags: c#, .net, terminal.gui

I use Terminal.Gui library: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs 
Is it possible to convert Dim to int? For example:

```cs
Window win = new Window("name") { 
  X = 0,
  Y = 0,
  Width = Dim.Fill(),
  Height = Dim.Fill()
};

int width = (int)win.Width; //There is "Cannot convert type Gui.Terminal.Dim to int" exception actually
```

Comment: [See for yourself](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs/blob/cfa00142f9e15a45c80082059c9b73cc542c13ae/Terminal.Gui/Core/PosDim.cs). You could try fetching [Bounds](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs/blob/cfa00142f9e15a45c80082059c9b73cc542c13ae/Terminal.Gui/Core/View.cs#L431), however...

Comment: I don't know the framework, but wouldn't it be win.Bounds.Size.Width? Edit:@Canton7 beat me to it.

Comment: canton7 and Palle Due Thenks! It's help for me!

Comment: What is `Dim` ?

Comment: A `Dim` can be either a percentage, an absolute value or a *margin* - DimFill has no actual size, just a margin. It doesn't make sense to convert it to an `int`. A `Dim()` was built to *specify screen-relative dimensions*, not retrieve absolute ones. What are you trying to do? If you want to have `Dim` calculate the actual size of a Window, it won't work, simply because a `DimFill` doesn't contain any size

Comment: In your case, your code specified a Window as large as the console screen, whatever that is. If the screen is resized, the window is resized as well. `Dim.Fill()` specifies a margin of 0. You already know that. So what `int` do you expect to get from `Dim`? The `0` you specified? You already know that. Or the current size of the window? `Dim` doesn't hold that

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the framework, but a quick peek at [the definition of the `Dim` object](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs/blob/master/Terminal.Gui/Core/PosDim.cs) shows that there are no methods that return an `int` (except `GetHashCode`) and as you have seen the object is not able to be casted to an int. So there is not a method for converting a `Dim` to an `int`.